# Get Wordpress Tags With 0 Posts Count

Tags: wordpress, tags

I'm trying to get some tags from wordpress database, tags that aren't assigned to any posts, so their post count is 0. 
The code i use selects only the tags with 1 or more posts assigned...

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'smallest'                  => 12,
            'largest'                   => 24,
            'unit'                      => 'px',
            'format'                    => 'flat',
            'orderby'                   => 'name',
            'order'                     => 'DESC',
            'exclude'                   => null,
            'include'                   => null,
            'topic_count_text_callback' => 'default_topic_count_text',
            'link'                      => 'view',
            'taxonomy'                  => 'post_tag',
            'echo'                      => true,
            'child_of'                  => null,
            'show_count' =>1
        );
        ?>
```

How can i get the tags with 0 posts assigned to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set hide_empty to false in the arguments of the [get_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) function.

```
get_tags(array('hide_empty' => false));
```

If you're using custom taxonomy, use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function.

```
get_terms('custom_tags', array('hide_empty' => false));
```

Comment: thanks so much! works! i didn't knew about that argument.